# Spotfire - Change datasource from SQL to excel

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I'm looking for a way to change my data source using script. In other words, I'm actually connected to the ​SQL database. I have some graphs, some tables, and some functions.

Is there a way to tell to Spotfire to switch from SQL data source to a folder present on my computer? This folder is just the same tables, with the same names but fixed, not changing yet at a date.

So, I'm looking for a button using Python script to change the data source. If you know a package/function to do so, I would be happy to try it.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: File>>Replace Data Table doesn't suit your use case?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I decide to freeze the database and create a dropdown to select which sources I want to use.